# How to implement the route relative redirects with the query params and the fragment

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing, angular-route-segment

I have one problem in developing Angular project.

I tried to find the solution on how to implement the route relative redirects with 
When the URL redirects, in which origin redirect has its relative the query params and the `fragment.`

For example, in the guide of Angular.io.

```
const heroesRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'heroes', redirectTo: '/superheroes' },
  { path: 'hero/:id', redirectTo: '/superhero/:id' },
  { path: 'superheroes',  component: HeroListComponent },
  { path: 'superhero/:id', component: HeroDetailComponent }
];
```

in hero-detail, `goback()` function to navigate back to the HeroListComponent.
I added `relativeTo: this.route`. But it is not working.

```
gotoHeroes(hero: Hero) {
  let heroId = hero ? hero.id : null;
  // Pass along the hero id if available
  // so that the HeroList component can select that hero.
  // Include a junk 'foo' property for fun.
  this.router.navigate(['/heroes', { id: heroId, foo: 'foo' }], {relativeTo: this.route});
}
```

When configuring to redirect to superheroes, I don't know how to implement this feature.

Answer (score 1):

You need a relative route, so depending on where you are, this should work to go back:

```
this.router.navigate(['../', { id: heroId, foo: 'foo' },  {relativeTo: this.route}]);
```

Comment: @pixelbilts, thanks for your anwswer. But it doesn't work. please check this guide sample.
https://angular.io/guide/router#migrating-urls-with-redirects
`/heros redirects to /superheros.`

Comment: heroes list component is not parent of hero detail component.

Comment: "Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment"

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like -

```
 this.router.navigate(
    ['hero','12345'],
    {
      relativeTo: this.route,
      queryParams: {
        type: 'value',
      },
    }
  );
```